# methods does not give confusion matrix in weka

Tags: weka

I want to do classification in weka. I am using some methods(Random Tree, Random Forest, Decision Table, RandomSubspace...) but they give results like below.

```
=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.1678
Mean absolute error                      0.4832
Root mean squared error                  0.4931
Relative absolute error                 96.6501 %
Root relative squared error             98.6323 %
Total Number of Instances           100000
```

However I want results as accurancy and confusion matrix. How can I get results like that?

Note: When I use small dataset, it gives results as confusion matrix. Can it be related with the size of dataset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of the training/testing in Weka depends on the type of the attribute that you are trying to predict. If your attribute is nominal, you will get a confusion matrix and accuracy value. If your attribute is numeric, you will get a correlation coefficient.

In your small and large datasets that you mention, what is your type of the attribute that you are predicting?

Comment: Datasets have mixed data. Small dataset has 3 nominal(categorical), 16 numeric(continious) attribute and 5000 sample. Large dataset has 37 nominal, 111 numeric attribute and 100000 sample.

Comment: Now, take a good look at the type of the attribute that you are trying to predict. My hunch is that on the large dataset you are trying to predict a numeric attribute and a nominal attribute on the small set. If that is the case then it is perfectly normal that you get confusion matrices for the small set but a correlation coefficient on the big set.

Answer (score 0):

I have run a 2-class problem using J48 and RandomForest with 100000 instances and the confusion matrix appeared correctly.  I additionally increased the problem complexity to run 20 different classes and the confusion matrix appeared correctly as well.

If you look under more options, please ensure that the 'output confusion matrix' is checked and see if this resolves the issue.